# Regular expression extractor in jmeter- to extract multiple values from response.?

Tags: regex, jmeter

The text is a response from my Jmeter request. I have to get the `ReportstepID` where `dataurl="TC/ReviewAdditionalInfo.aspx?`.
`ReportID`,`Facility ID's` are parameters.

```
dataload="0" dataurl="TC/ReviewAdditionalInfo.aspx?ReportID=319844&FacilityID=201217&ReportStepID=2916158&RptShortName=TC" 
dataload="1" dataurl="ReviewFeeExemption.aspx?ReportID=319844&FacilityID=201217&ReportStepID=2916162&RptShortName=TC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add regular expression:

Regular expression: ReviewAdditionalInfo.aspx\?ReportID=(\d+)&FacilityID=(\d+)&ReportStepID=(\d+)

Template $3$

Match No. 1

Comment: Don't you need the value of ReportStepID_g3=2916401? Use  ${ReportStepID_g3} after it

Answer (score 0):

You regex is `"ReviewFeeExemption.aspx?.*ReportStepID=([0-9]+)"`

Group 1 contain your id