# Regular expression extractor to store time string in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

Please help me to use Regex Extractor in Jmeter

"StatusDate\" style=\"text-align:left\"\u003e10/31/2017 3:17:00 PM\u003c  is response data

I wish to extract time to a string 10/31/2017 3:17:00 PM.

Comment: Please show us what you tried before asking on SO. Also, can you provide some more input data so that we can figure out the best way to parse it ?

Comment: I need to pass 10/31/2017 3:17:00 PM in the next jmeter request. So i wish to extract it as a regular expression. "StatusDate\" style=\"text-align:left\"\u003e10/31/2017 3:17:00 PM\u003c is the response from previous request.

Comment: check my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142305/regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter-to-extract-multiple-values-from-response/45143562#45143562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex such as :

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s+(AM|PM)
```

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/5RcQPS/1).

Now I'm not sure if this is the most standard one for your type of input data as you only provided one example.

Comment: i Ve shared sample previous question. Need to have answer in the same format as i am not good at Regex